# Beagleboneblack and TSC2013 touchscreen driver

Tags: beagleboneblack, touchscreen

everybody:
    Now, I'm using Beagleboneblack board with bone-debian-9.4-lxqt-armhf-2018-06-17-4gb.img, and I have a [touchscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl74h.png) chip that is TSC2013 with I2C interface, I want to use this chip drive a LCD(800x600),but I failed, I want to know what is wrong with my I2C, who can help me? 
    Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question would be more likely to receive an answer if you added more detail about how you failed.  What specific error did you observed, and how can someone reproduce your steps?  See here for community guidelines on providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem you're having- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely vague in terms of what you've attempted so far and what your problems are.

You have to do a bit of work to ensure that i2c is functioning properly on your BBB.

[You should follow this tutorial](https://www.teachmemicro.com/beaglebone-black-i2c-tutorial/)

If there are no active i2c ports, then you have to look into changing the `uEnv.txt` file to tell the BBB to activate an i2c port when it boots.

Once you have enabled your desired i2c port. Then use `i2c-tools` to fully debug the active i2c port.

[Here is a very good tutorial about the basics of setting up i2c on the BBB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C2zk6B-eLU)

Comment: I'm very sorry about my vague question and thanks a lot for your answer. Because I really don't know how to use "stack overflow", I want to communicate with you directly, could you give me your contact information such as QQ or WeChat ? I'm looking forward to your reply. Thank you very much.